# How to store multiple instance of an class object in a dictionary and use the first instance as the key

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to store multiple instance of a class object in a dictionary and i would like to use the first instance as the key.

i used the following:

```
Obj = {ClassName("cust"),ClassName("address"),....}
```

in my ClassName, i define the *init* as follow:

```
def __init__(self, mydata,Type):
    dictionary={}
    self.data=mydata
    key=self.data[0]
    dictionary[key]=self.data[1:]

    for k,v in dictionary.items():
        print (k,v)
```

but content of the dictionary is :

```
c ust
a address
c ust
```

but what i would like to have is cust address on the same line. How can i fix this?

Comment: What do you mean you want the first instance as the Key? What you have declared as `Obj` is a set.

Comment: like in that example, cust is the key of the dictionary

Comment: Okay... So you want something that looks like this? `{'cust':['address','cust',...]}` Your question doesn't really make clear what you are trying to do...

Comment: well, let me put is simply, i am trying to put all the instance created in a dictionary, on the same line but separated by a tab. The dicitionary i created is in my class and i want the first instance created to be my key. in that case, my first instance is cust. Thank you

Comment: You do realize that according to your code your Keys are `('c','a','c')` and the values are `('ust','address', 'ust')` but this is also impossible because a dictionary cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: yes, how do i make cust to be key in this case?

Comment: `key=self.data[0]` Right here your assigning Key to be the first item of whatever `self.data` is. Since you said `self.data = mydata` and `mydata` is a string, the first item of a string is the first letter.

Comment: Let me get this straight, you want `'cust'` to be the `key` and you want `'address'` to be the value? Because this is not at all what you have been asking to do. If you want to do that then you should just, do this `ClassName('cust', 'address')` and then have your class do this to it `dictionary['cust'] = 'address'`

Comment: ok thank you a lot. Sorry if my questions might seems obvious, i am new in programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print the dictionary contents on one line, do something like this.

```
dictionary = YourDictionary
keys = dictionary.keys()
myString = ""
for key in keys:
    myString = myString + key + ", " + dictionary[key]


print myString
```